# how to skip user to go to checkout page,add a third party checkout button on cart page

Tags: checkout, cart, payment-gateway

I am integrating `Pilibaba payment gateway` in my magento site . they have there checkout form . So can `anybody explain me how can i add a button on cart page` directly which will redirect me to that `pilibaba` request page. i am worried because orders are created in magento after place order step in checkout page .
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question correct. You want a button, so the user is redirected to a checkout form of a third party service and afterwards you want to have this order in magento?

## Inside magento

Implement Pilibaba as payment method in magento, as every other payment method. Just search for "implement own payment method in magento" on a search engine of your choice

## outside of magento

### Checkout

Implement a form, where all information are submitted to pilibaba, when you hit the submit button, then make the checkout there.

### Sync back into magento

The question now is, how to get the information back to magento:

1. sync it back. Somewhere inside of pilibaba the information is saved, so "just grab it and write an order"
2. save all the information into an order before you click the button and go to pilibaba, the problem is, that you can only be sure, that the customer paid, if pilibaba has something like Paypals IPN.

Comment: HI Fabian  Thanks for your reply . On cart page here is a link proceed to checkout . below that i want to add a button checkout on pilibaba. but all processing and order saving is done on checkout page in magento . so can you please give me an idea how can i do it . second option is to skip billing and shipping forms from checkout if user want to pay using pilibaba

Comment: I gave my best to give you an idea. This question is quite complex and too broad to answer it in detail.